# What field of law would I specialize in for cases dealing with technology?

Tags: united-states

I am considering getting into the field of law. I am currently an engineer and technologist. What field of law would I need to specialize in to get cases that deal with technology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Patent law, especially patent prosecution (writing patent applications and working with the US Patent & Trademark Office to get those applications granted), is the most common area of law for scientists and engineers to enter. Patent prosecution does not require a law degree, but does require a science or engineering undergraduate degree.

On the other hand, patent litigation (going to court over alleged infringement of granted patents) and other technology-focused areas of law (e.g., IP transactions) do generally require a law degree (and not a technical degree), and so you would have to spend a good deal of time and money on law school.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious specialty is patent law specifically (which usually requires an engineering or science degree) and intellectual property law generally (which often does not).

But, representing technology firms in their business dealings (e.g. in securities law disclosures of risks that investors face if they invest in a technology) is also relevant.